# Unix command sort by number of occurances of a specific character

Tags: file, unix, sorting, grep

I have a file with this format:

```
key value:value:value:value
key value:value
key value
key value:value:value
```

where there is a key at the first column and in the second a list of values delimited with :.
Is there any command that I can sort this file based on the number of occurances of : in the value list i.e. from the most values to least e.g. the previous example will be like this:

```
key value:value:value:value
key value:value:value
key value:value
key value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
awk -F: '{$0=NF"#"$0}1' file|sort -nr|sed 's/.*#//'
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "key value:value:value:value
key value:value
key value
key value:value:value"|awk -F: '{$0=NF"#"$0}1'|sort -nr|sed 's/.*#//'
key value:value:value:value
key value:value:value
key value:value
key value
```

**EDIT**

the sort tool on linux/unix box is very powerful. but it sorts against column/fields, not based on some calculation. Your requirement needs do calculation first and sort against on the result.

So I just add a new column, which is the count of `:`, then sort it with sort command, at the end remove that column.

```
awk adds the column
sort does sort
sed removes that column
```

you can remove those pipes and see output, then you will see how it worked.